# Indexing several editions of a same event

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing

We have a website presenting sport events, mostly annual. Each URL contains the event's year and name. E.g:

- `/marathon/my-event-2014`
- `/marathon/my-event-2015`
- `/marathon/my-event-2016`

(the reason why several editions of the same event coexist at the same time is that registration may be open for an edition while the previous edition is not over)

When 2014 edition is over, how to inform search engines that `/marathon/my-event-2015` is a better answer than `/marathon/my-event-2014` to a generic search for "my event"?

So far, we could think of the following solutions, without being sure of the implications of each one:

1. redirect pasts editions to the current edition: `/my-event-2014` => `/my-event-2015`
2. declare the current edition as canonical (although I don't think it really qualifies)
3. use the next/previous `<link>` tags to declare all editions of a same event as a series

Comment: Can you clarify why this question doesn't fit? When it comes to SEO, answers are often based on expert experience rather than references since search engine algorithms are not public.

Comment: I've rephrased it. Hope it fits better the rules now.

Comment: Still wrong? If you could explain why this question has been closed, I and other newbies could learn from it.